# Mocking emit function of SocketIO with Mockk

Tags: kotlin, socket.io, mockk

Currently I am trying to mock the callback of a socket.emit method which is wrapped in the Ack class of SocketIO.

My function to send a specific event looks like this:

```
fun send(info: info): Completable {
    return Completable.create { emitter ->
        _socket.emit("info", info.mapRepresentation, Ack() {
            fun call(vararg args: Any?) {
                emitter.onComplete()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Ack class of socketIO:

```
package io.socket.client;

/**
 * Acknowledgement.
 */
public interface Ack {

    public void call(Object... args);

}
```

Now I want to mock the socket.emit method so that I call that Ack.call method for every socket.emit call:

```
@Test
fun sendInfo_socketConfigured_infoSent() {
    val info = info(123, "x", "x")
    testSubject.send(info).test().assertComplete()
    every {
        socket.emit("info", info.mapRepresentation, any())
    } answers {
        thirdArg<Ack>.call()
    }
}
```

The issue is, I don't know how to exactly call this Ack.call method with Mockk, because Mockk expects an emitter in the answers block, but I provide a Unit. Am I even doing it right with my approach to test the method testSubject.send()?

I am using 'io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a principle saying you shouldn't pursue this any further: [Don't mock what you don't](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don%27t-mock-what-you-don%27t-own)

---

To solve these scenarios, it's good practice to create a wrapper around the hard-to-integrate part. This technique allows you to create a mock or stub for it in test scenarios. Using a wrapper, you would pass an instance of that wrapper to the `testSubject` which uses it inside `send`. Without knowing much about the domain and context, just to give you an idea, something like the following could help:

```
interface SocketEmitter(){
   fun emit(socket: Socket, event: ...) // maybe socket can even go into constructor list to make it a field
} 

//default implementation
class DefaultSocketEmitter(): SocketEmitter {
   override fun emit(...) = socket.emit(...)
}

//in your test you would pass a stub or mock if verification is needed (which isn't most of the time)
createTestSubject(object: SocketEmitter { 
    override fun emit(...) = Unit // whatever makes sense
})
```